# How to align text in two different cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface, xamarin

I'm using `Xamarin.Forms` in my project, however, this problem could be also mapped to native development. I have two different cells, one is default `TextCell` (in native it would be just a `UITableViewCell` with `Basic` style) and the other is a custom cell with `Label` and some extra things.

I use both cells in the same table view, so I would like the text to be aligned horizontally. For custom cell I was using left margin `15`, however, on iOS 13 on iPhone 11 it turned out that margin is different than on iPhone 7 for example. As a result, I have unaligned cells with different left margins.

I know I could use custom cells for all rows, but maybe there is a better approach? Is it possible to retrieve this system margin and set the same in another cell?

Comment: Some code to show what you have could be usefull to determine the best way to solve this, without it, i may only guess if its gonna work or not, but when it comes to alignments, it better to always use the layout vertical/horizontal options to Center the elements inside it, as left and right margins may differ from the Device you are using

Answer (score 0):

1.set textLabel text in order to get its leftMargin and hide it

```
self.textLabel.text = @"";
```

2.get margin in layoutSubviews

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
[super layoutSubviews];
CGFloat leftMargin = self.textLabel.frame.origin.x;
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is also in the propagation of left margin to other cells. I was thinking that maybe there is some way to determine label margin before `layoutSubviews`. Like a property in `UITableView` or something.

Comment: @WojciechKulik I don't think there is such a property exist.

Comment: You can find the margins of all sized devices, add an property to the UITableViewCell category, and return the margin according to the size of the device in get method 
`@implementation UITableViewCell (Margin)

static char kMarginKey;

- (CGFloat)wk_margin {
    id value = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &kMarginKey);
    return [value floatValue];
}

- (void)setWk_margin:(CGFloat)wk_margin {
    CGFloat margin = 0.0;
    // set margin according to device size
    // ...
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &kMarginKey, @(margin), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
}

@end`

Answer (score 0):

You can find the margins of all sized devices, add an property to the UITableViewCell category, and return the margin according to the size of the device in get method; This is not a good solution, but we can get the margins of devices of different sizes

```c
@interface UITableViewCell (Margin)

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat wk_margin;

@end

@implementation UITableViewCell (Margin)

static char kMarginKey;

- (CGFloat)wk_margin {
    id value = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &kMarginKey);
    return [value floatValue];
}

- (void)setWk_margin:(CGFloat)wk_margin {
    CGFloat margin = 0.0;
    // TODO :set margin according to device size
    // ...
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &kMarginKey, @(margin), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
}

@end
```